# Device Sreenshot not working in Android Debug Monitor

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to take screenshot in DDMS, to use Hierarchy Viewer and learn about views. But when i try to use button Take Screenshot, always returns black screen. See below:

[image]

Erro log:

```
01-26 10:22:22.980: E/gralloc_goldfish(922): gralloc_alloc: Mismatched usage flags: 320 x 480, usage 333
01-26 10:22:22.980: W/GraphicBufferAllocator(922): alloc(320, 480, 1, 00000333, ...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
01-26 10:22:22.980: E/(922): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=320, h=480) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
01-26 10:22:22.980: E/BufferQueue(1788): [ScreenshotClient] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceComposer::createGraphicBuffer failed
```

My emulator:
API 19 - Android 4.4.2 - Device 3.2"  QVGA (ADP2) (320, 480), using Host GPU

Anyone know how can i solve this?

Comment: Maybe you have this problem: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60359 , try to disable Host GPU for check. Unfortunately, it seems that there is no solution for that still.

Comment: Do you get the correct image with: adb shell screencap -p | sed 's/\r$//' > screen.png ? If no, it is probably due to this Host GPU issue, if not, it should be something else on your computer not in the emulator.

Answer (score 3):

Turning off "Use Host GPU" for this AVD will fix this.